# rails sessions issue when invalid user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, authentication

Right now I am trying to authenticate a user.  This process works.  Right now the login for a user has the field username and password.  If a user types in the correct information, it works.  If the user types in a valid username and incorrect password, it works.  If the user types in an invalid username, it does not work.  Here is my create action in the sessions controller:

```
  def create
    user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])
    redirect_to root_url if user == nil
    if user.password == params[:password]
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to user_path(user.id), notice: "Logged in!"
    else
      flash.now.alert = "not logged in"
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end
```

The error that I am getting is that there is no method password for user.  I know this and put in the line

```
redirect_to root_url if user == nil
```

and I also had the line

```
redirect_to root_url unless user.password
```

Both of these aren't working and are not redirecting back to the root url.

Comment: The form is a login form.  The user is being created in the admin.  I am just trying to validate is it is a user.  The problem is if the username is not found in the User class user in the create action becomes nil.  With that in mind, I attempted to say if the user is nil then go back to the root url.  That part is not working.

Comment: `if user && user.password == params[:password]` ????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it

```
if user && user.password == params[:password]
```